# REST Codeigniter, jquery/ajax does not display response

Tags: rest, jquery, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to get a helloworld type program working with REST CI/jquery. I've included my (really rudimentary) REST controller, view file and javascript file and am hoping that the error that has eluded me jumps out at you.

Two issues:

1. The response I get from the server does not get displayed - the screen gets refreshed instead (I *know* this is some very basic thing I've missed). If I step through the code, I see the display of the result but then, screen gets refreshed. And somehow, I cannot step into my "success" function. Why, oh why?

2.Upon success, I'd like to redirect the user to another url, say, www.google.com. Would I do this in the javascript file? or server side?

Thank you in advance for helping me!

[Added after solving the issue: My problem has nothing to do with REST or Codeigniter. A purely javascript problem]
The REST Controller:

```
<?php
    require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

    class Myex extends REST_Controller {
      function contact_post(){
        $result=array();
        $fname=$this->post('fname');
        $lname=$this->post('lname');
        $result['message']="contact_post has your name";
        $result['fname']=$fname."XX";
        $result['lname']=$lname."YY";
        $this->response($result,200);
      }
    }
?>
```

The view file:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header')?>
    <div id="input-div"> 
        <form name="cookieform" id="login" method="post">
          First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="text"/>
          Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="text"/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id='submit' class="page"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="resp-div"> 
    response goes here
    </div>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer')?>
```

The javascript file:

```
function postsuccess(output) {
    $('#soln-div').html(output.message +'for user '+output.fname+' whose last name is '+output.lname).show('slow');
}
function post_contact() {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var output;
        var fdata,res;
        var furl=global_siteurl+'/myex/contact';
        var fname=$('#fname').val();
        var lname=$('#lname').val();
        fdata='fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname;
        res=$.ajax({
        url: furl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
            data:fdata,
            success: function(output) { 
                postsuccess(output); 
          }
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_contact();
    post_contact();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have called your ajax function upon submission of form you can prevent refreshing of page in 2 ways:
   (a) Use `<input type="button" />` instead of submit call your ajax function on this button or
   (b) Use `return false;` in your success function of ajax request.
2. You can redirect to any url in javascript using `window.top.location = 'url-to-redirect';`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Turned out to have *nothing* to do with REST and everything to do with my poor javascript skill. Much obliged, Shayan!